# Make UITextView scroll action hide a UILabel

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

Basically, what I want to do is detect when a user scrolls inside a text view, and then hide a label (Smoothly fade out, if possible). (The label indicates to scroll to view the rest of the text, but I don't want it to still show after the user has done so.)

If you could include in your answer the code used in the h/m files, it would be greatly appreciated.

Updated code for future reference:

.h

```
@interface myViewController : UIViewController

@property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UILabel *label;
```

.m

```
@synthesize label;

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)textView
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
        label.alpha = 0;
    }];
}
```

Then make sure to set the UITextView delegate to self.

Comment: What have you tried? What code have you used that didn't work? http://whathaveyoutried.com/

Comment: I'm not exactly sure, my development computer is about 30 minutes from my location, lol.

Comment: Well I recommend updating your question with code and examples. Stack Overflow is meant for specific questions that we can help with, not for us to create and hand you free code. I work for $50 an hour if you're interested in contracting. Otherwise you'll have to show you've tried and failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use UIScrollView's delegate method `– scrollViewDidScroll:` to detect that the user has scrolled, and fade out your label with a UIView animation block, like so:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
    label.alpha = 0
}];
```

Comment: I added "@property(nonatomic,retain) NSArray *label;" to my .h and synthesized it in .m. I receive error "Property 'alpha' not found on object of type 'NSArray *'"

Comment: btw- I'm using storyboards

Comment: The label shouldn't be an NSArray, it should be a UILabel. If you're using storyboards, declare it as `@property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UILabel *label;` in your .h and link it in interface builder.

Comment: Is the method being called? You may not have set the delegate on the text view.

Comment: Hmm.. sorry for this, but I'm pretty sure I have... Explain? I'm not exactly the most experienced in this, if you haven't noticed.

Comment: Did you set the text views's delegate to MoreInfo_35? ie, at some point, did you say myTextView.delegate = self or link it in interface builder?

Comment: You just blew my mind, lol. Thanks man. Though I gotta say, that was a stupid mistake, even for me..